# Character encoding used by Excel

Tags: excel, csv, encoding

I am generating csv files to be imported in Adwords Editor. My problem is that I have to open the csv in Excel and save it again because the Editor doesn't encode the characters correctly.

How can I find which character encoding is being used by Excel when saving a csv?